# Laravel Routes - how to "mod rewrite"?

Tags: laravel, mod-rewrite, routes

I'm developing an API. Say I have the following endpoints that should output the same resources:

1. /api/users/5/comments
2. /api/comments?user-id=5

I have a controller to handle the `users` endpoint, and I have a controller to handle the `comments` endpoint. Each controller also handles all the filtering, sorting, etc. required.

Since the two endpoints provided should output the same data, is there a way I can tell Laravel that in routes? I don't want to use the implementation of #2 URL above to also output the appropriate response for #1 URL.

I guess I'm looking for something akin to MOD REWRITE in .htaccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't pointing to the same controller suffice?

```
Route::get('/api/users/{userid}/comments', 'CommentController@index');
Route::get('/api/comments', 'CommentController@index');
```

Then handling the specific case if it has user-id provided.

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $commentQuery = Comment::query();

    $commentQuery->when($request->query->has('user-id'), function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('user-id', $request->query->get('user-id'));
    });

    return $commentQuery->get();
}
```

Comment: Alternatively putting business logic in a service like class would be best for big applications, but then you can create two different controllers utilizing the same service instead which is the same idea.

Comment: I'm digesting your solution. What if `comments` had `media` associated with it? How to deal with `/api/users/5/comments/100/media`?

Comment: Or if `users` could have `media`, which could have `comments`, which could have `media`: `/api/users/5/media/100/comments/50/media`

Comment: Make new controllers for them? controllers should only handle one thing eg. CommentController handle comments CommentMediaController handle comment medias etc.

Comment: I would end up with `UserMediaController`, `UserMediaCommentController`, `UserMediaCommentMediaController`, etc. Not sure about that.

Comment: Naming and namespaces can solve most of the naming inconvenience, i think the key take away is that you keep your logic in your application so developers know what is going on, with mod rewrite you obfuscate what is happening. This approach is what i have seen working companies with bigger platforms and i think it is the best approach afaik due to keeping your logic in your application. If you do not like it that is fair.

Comment: I don't want to do a mod rewrite. I was looking for something akin to mod rewrite, but within Laravel.

Comment: But isnt pointing to the same controller actually that?